# Specifically regarding number styles, trying to understand otfinfo output for subsequent use with fontspec

Tags: fontspec, opentype

An example first. I have the Monotype Baskerville Pro fonts. This is the `otfinfo` output for its  Regular font:

```
$ otfinfo -f ~/Library/Fonts/BaskervilleMTPro-Regular.otf 
aalt    Access All Alternates
c2sc    Small Capitals From Capitals
case    Case-Sensitive Forms
dnom    Denominators
frac    Fractions
kern    Kerning
liga    Standard Ligatures
lnum    Lining Figures
numr    Numerators
onum    Oldstyle Figures
ordn    Ordinals
salt    Stylistic Alternates
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
smcp    Small Capitals
ss01    Stylistic Set 1
sups    Superscript
```

So, I can see `onum` and `lnum` but not `pnum` or `tnum`. Now, by trial and error (see MWE below) I can determine that in fact the lining figures are tabular (monospaced) and the oldstyle figures are proportional.

But `onum` (oldstyle) vs `lnum` (lining) are (I believe, perhaps this is the core of my misunderstanding) logically independent to `pnum` (proportional) vs `tnum` (tabular/monospaced). That is a font could offer any of the following four possibilities, e.g.

```
             Lining    Oldstyle
Proportional    ✔︎          ✔︎
Tabular         ✔︎          ✘
```

But if a font did offer three alternate number styles what would the output of `otfinfo` look like?

Right now I am just using the following test document and seeing what the output is and what is in the log, but I’m sure there is a better way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville MT Pro}%  <— replace with font of your choice

\begin{document}

\section{Proportional Oldstyle}

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}}
11223344\\
99999999}

\section{Tabular Oldstyle}

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}}
11223344\\
99999999}

\section{Proportional Lining}

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,Lining}}
11223344\\
99999999}

\section{Tabular Lining}

{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}
11223344\\
99999999}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not all fonts support all combinations (though you could fake them by adding features in `luatex`, by playing with the kerning).

Comment: @Thérèse yes, I know that not all fonts support all the combinations. I am trying to figure out how to determine what combinations a font does support other than by trial and error.

Comment: Looking at the feature file with a program like FontForge is the best way I know of.  `otfinfo` doesn’t suffice.  E.g., try running `otfinfo` on TeX Gyre Pagella.